# Laravel 6, "Missing Required Parameter For Route"

Tags: laravel-6

There
i Have An Error In Laravel 6 Routes in This Code:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'list', 'as' => 'list.'], function() 
{
     Route::resource('/', 'StaffsController'); // List
});
```

In Route List Give Me An Empty Parameter That I Can't Pass It Using :

```
{{ route('admin.users.staffs.list.edit', ['id' => $person->id]) }}
```

> Route List

```
 admin/users/staffs/list/{}/edit                   | admin.users.staffs.list.edit
```

Thank You

Comment: You can use {{ route('admin.users.staffs.list.edit',  $person->id) }}

Comment: Yes It Works In Blade, But After Submitting It Gives Me A 404 | Not Found

Comment: Did you try manually naming the parameter as specified here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters ?

Comment: Please can you show the code for your `StaffsController` (or at least the `edit` method including the declaration).

Comment: `public function edit($id)
    {
        $admin = Admin::findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin::users.staffs.list.edit', compact('admin'));
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
{{ route('admin.users.staffs.list.edit', $person->id) }}
```

if not working check route name

Comment: It Works For The Blade Only, But After Click On Edit, This Url Gives Me 404 | Not Found

Comment: @Amakye Did you get this working?  I have the same issue with Laravel 6

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group([
    'as'     => 'admin.'
], function()
{
    Route::group([
        'as'     => 'users.'
    ], function()
    {
        Route::group([
            'as'     => 'staff.'
        ], function()
        {
           Route::resource('list', 'StaffsController'); // List
        });
    });
});
```

**There is no need for grouping resource route.**

Btw you can always call this command `php artisan route:list` to see what's going on inside of the route.